# Using Geoserver and PostgreSQL to build a web mapping tool?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, web-mapping, open-source-gis

I've been an ESRI user and a Carto user and like both tools but I am now hoping to build my own web-mapping platform. The issue is, I have no web-development experience other than the little I've taught myself. I want my mapping platform to be able to run SQL queries and to store data safely (some datasets I only want to make available via a link, and not make the data shareable/scrapeable).

Am I even looking in the right direction?

Can this GeoServer + PostgreSQL mix get me what I want?

Comment: As it stands I think that your question is too broad for focused Q&A.  Many people may have an opinion on whether you are "looking in the right direction".  To seek and throw around ideas rather than telling us what you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck with a single aspect of your project we have the under utilized [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

Comment: Another source of useful ideas and experience may be our [self-assembling FAQ on using GeoServer and PostgreSQL together](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgis+geoserver?sort=frequent).